# Web accessibility - Should my title be tabable?

Tags: html, accessibility

I am delving into the confusing world of web accessibility and trying to retrofit my HTML code to have better accessibility with things such as aria-labels etc.

Trying to tab through my webpage app-header, I am not able to select the page title... Should I be able to, or am I worrying about nothing?

The burger menu and the search bar icon are able to be tabbed. I'm just wondering whether the text should be? Because it is not being read out either.

**FYI: I am using ChromeVOX as a screen reader**

[image]

```
<app-header class="topHeader" fixed shadow slot="header"> <!-- effects="waterfall" not needed as nothing scrolls behind header bar -->
    <app-toolbar>
        <paper-icon-button id="toggleDrawer" icon="menu" on-click="toggleMenu" title="Expand menu" aria-title="Expand menu"></paper-icon-button>
        <div main-title>App Header Goes Here</div>
        <search-bar></search-bar> <!-- This is an external element being called in -->
    </app-toolbar>
</app-header>
```

Comment: I changed it to <h1>App header</h1> but still nothing. I have tried to force it with tab-index and nothing. I will take the advice of @Quentin below and do nothing with it for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does clicking on it **do** anything (navigate to another page, open up a new set of options using DOM manipulation, etc) that isn't behaviour duplicated by some other control?

If so, then it should be possible to tab to it.

If not, that isn't needed.

(If it does nothing, then it is counter productive to allow it to be focused).

Comment: Thanks for the info Quentin. The title doesn't do anything at all, it is simply the app header as you can see from the code. I just thought that it may need to be read like regular text on a page etc.

Comment: You don't need to focus regular text to read it. You need to focus it to interact with it (interacting with a link takes you to a new page, for example).

Comment: I get what you mean. I think I just worded my answer wrongly (it's been a long day of trying to read w3.org haha).